# Onnx import failed

Tags: python, c#, tensorflow, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use object detection.
-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1br6gW-8Ss&ab_channel=WhenMathsMeetCoding

I used TensorFlow to make the `.pd` and converted it to `.onnx.`
->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8dbnpzxpQQ&ab_channel=JayanthK

The convert method is `"python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model TensorFlow-model-path --output model.onnx".`

The problem is that when I import `.onnx` into Unity, It is failed.

[success import other people .onnx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNhdJ.png)

[Fail import my .onnx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su5Je.png)

**

### Error 1 :

```py
OnnxImportException: Unknown type Loop encountered while parsing layer StatefulPartitionedCall/map/while_loop:0.

Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Err (Unity.Barracuda.Model model, System.String layerName, System.String message, System.String extendedMessage, System.String debugMessage) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:3434)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.ConvertOnnxModel (Onnx.ModelProto onnxModel) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:2954)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Convert (Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream inputStream) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:170)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Convert (System.String filePath) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:98)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNXModelImporter.OnImportAsset (UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImportContext ctx) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Editor/ONNXModelImporter.cs:65)
UnityEditor.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter.GenerateAssetData (UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImportContext ctx) (at <d63e58d1bc4b489593159fa6218bc0e6>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

### **Error 2 :**

```py
Asset import failed, "Assets/Models/model.onnx" > OnnxImportException: Unknown type Loop encountered while parsing layer StatefulPartitionedCall/map/while_loop:0.

Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Err (Unity.Barracuda.Model model, System.String layerName, System.String message, System.String extendedMessage, System.String debugMessage) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:3434)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.ConvertOnnxModel (Onnx.ModelProto onnxModel) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:2954)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Convert (Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream inputStream) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:170)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNX.ONNXModelConverter.Convert (System.String filePath) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/ONNX/ONNXModelConverter.cs:98)
Unity.Barracuda.ONNXModelImporter.OnImportAsset (UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImportContext ctx) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Editor/ONNXModelImporter.cs:65)
UnityEditor.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter.GenerateAssetData (UnityEditor.AssetImporters.AssetImportContext ctx) (at <d63e58d1bc4b489593159fa6218bc0e6>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Hoping someone can help me!!!

Comment: Please use code tag to highlighted all error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.